# How to get a custom attribute of user object in Parse, swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to get the `mobileNumber` of current user from Parse in swift.

I can get the username by this:

```
var user  = PFUser.currentUser()
var userNameText = user.username
```

But, if I use:

```
var userMobileNumber = user["mobileNumber"]
```

am getting error as `Cannot subscript a value of type PFUser? with an index of type String`

Can I get it only by query method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol, I found the answer so soon...

I can use: `var userMobileNumber = user.objectForKey("mobileNumber") as! String`

I will let the question so that other beginners could make use of it.